# Do Docker Containers work equally well on Windows/Mac/linux

Tags: docker, virtualization

I'm not clear if a Docker container will work on any environment that has Docker running, or if some are aimed at Linux, some at Windows ectera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  If you have Docker for Windows, configured to run Windows containers, they won't work on a Linux operating system.  If you have Docker for Windows, configured to run Linux containers, containers there should run fine there and in a Linux operating system.

Comment: Okay, so there are seperate container types, but you can configure WIndows to act like its linux, thanks that answers my question.